# Qt control not working properly in custom Linux

Tags: qt, touch, embedded-linux, buildroot

I'm trying to develop a Qt application to a custom linux built with Buildroot for Raspberry PI 4. My goal is to make an GUI through Touch interface and for that I'm using an USB Infrared frame.

### My Problem

When I try to interact with a frame, I can move the dial, but when i try to use another dial it behaves like the first pressed dial didn't get released (like when you press mouse 1 and don't release it anymore).
It just stays selected and I can't interact with any other thing in the application.

I run the program using this command :

```
./dials -platform linuxfb
```

and here is [the frame I am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3vtM.png).

### What I tried so far

I tried some of the examples provided by Qt that came with buildroot. They seem to work just fine with the mouse in both the Raspberry and in Ubuntu (my PC). Also I tried the same examples in Ubuntu with the touch frame and they also worked flawlessly .

I've set QT_QPA_EVDEV_TOUCHSCREEN_PARAMETERS:/dev/input/event1 , if I don't do this it doesn't even move anything.